# How to derive element-wise vector multiplication using chain rule

Tags: partial-derivative, chain-rule

Given the equation below, how should I treat the vector $a$?

$\frac{\partial}{\partial b} a \odot coth(Mb) $

$a\in R^n, b \in R^m $ and $M \in R^{n \times m}$

These are the chain rule steps I took:

$x = Mb$,
$x' = M$

$y = coth(x)$,
$y' = −csch^2(x)$

$z = a \odot y$,
$z' = a' \odot y + a \odot y'$  which is $a \odot cos(x)$

This doesn't feel right. What I am missing?

What should vector/matrix size should I expect to have in the end if n=2 and m=3?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: How is it defined the function $\sin(Mb)$ with $Mb\in \mathbb{R}^n$ ?

Comment: That's true. I have just realised. I will edit and change it to coth to work with $e^x$